# Adding a bean of hibernate sessionFactory in @configuration casues : "Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration."

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory

Everything was working fine until I added the sessionFactory bean in my @configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {

        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are
        // reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return props;
    }

    // need a helper method
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }

    //@Bean(name="hibernateSessionFactory")
    //@Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Does the addition of this bean conflicts the default functioning of springboot? I am using a separate JpaRepository for spring security related stuffs which is totally unrelated to the hibernate stuffs of my application.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a `SessionFactory`? Why not use JPA instead of plain Hibernate? If you really want a session you can use `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);` to get the Hibernate native `Session`. You get the error because as of Hibernate 5.4 (I believe) the `SessionFactory` is an `EntityManagerFactory` and (part of) the Spring Boot autoconfiguration will back off.

Comment: Show us your full configuration page. How are you setting up the datasource, etc...?

Comment: @eyoeldefare I have added the full configuration page